# same space between rows and columns bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to make a grid in bootstrap with same space between rows and columns. Using padding 0,0,0 , leaves cero space , but if I use padding 10,10,10,10 it does not work leving diferent spaces  between the rows and columns. see my code :

```
<style>
.box {
    padding:0 0px 0 0px;
}

</style>
<div class="container">   
<br><br>
<div class="row  margin-bottom-0">
<div class="col-md-4 box">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 box">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 box" style="background-color:red;   height: 150px;">  </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 box" style="background-color:yellow;height: 150px;">  </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 box" style="background-color:pink;height: 250px;">  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 box">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 box" style="background-color:DeepPink;height: 250px;">  </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 box">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 box" style="background-color:darkblue;height: 150px;">    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 box" style="background-color:orange;  height: 150px;">    </div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 box ">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 box">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 box" style="background-color:magenta;height: 150px;"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 box" style="background-color:yellow; height: 150px;"> </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 box" style="background-color:BlueViolet;height: 250px;">    </div>
</div>
```

I want something like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2BTM.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do: if you're nesting columns, use rows with them as well (you have columns inside `<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 box">`) and place your content (**box**) inside the columns, not on the same line as the column class. Then add your padding requirements.

See Grid Nesting in the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting).

See working Snippet.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.grid > [class*='col-'] {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row grid">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="box" style="background-color:red; height: 150px;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="box" style="background-color:yellow;height: 150px;">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="box" style="background-color:pink;height: 250px;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row grid">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="box" style="background-color:DeepPink;height: 250px;">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="box" style="background-color:darkblue;height: 150px;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="box" style="background-color:orange;  height: 150px;">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="row grid">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="box" style="background-color:magenta;height: 150px;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="box" style="background-color:yellow; height: 150px;">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="box" style="background-color:BlueViolet;height: 250px;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```